# How to make website URL work as prefix in React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-navigation, deep-linking

### What I'm trying to do

I'm currently trying to setup `deep linking` into my `React Native` app. I'm creating a share functionality so that the user can show his friends a page inside my app. I want the same behaviour when you click a link of Netflix or Spotify - It directly opens the app even if it was closed.

### What I already done

In order to do that, I created a `Nextjs` web application to give my links some good-looking meta tags.

Also, I have configured my `Navigator` using `React Navigation v5`.

```
const config = {
    screens: {
        Feed: {
            screens:{
                LocalInside: "share/:localId"
            }
        },
        Ranking: 'ranking'
    },
};

const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https://[myapp]-web.vercel.app', '[myapp]://'],
    config,
};
...
<NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
```

> Note: Both links have the same suffix, that is "/share/:localID"

### The problem

Finally, I learned that in order to test the `deep link` I could use `uri-scheme` so I ran

```
npx uri-scheme open [myapp]://share/[someLocalID] --android
```

It worked. But I couldn't get my vercel.app link to work. Not on Android Browser, neither using `uri-scheme`.

**So I want to know how can I make my Nextjs website URL directly open my app the same way the uri-scheme command does.**

Comment: I'm not sure I completely get your problem, but it seems to me you're trying to do two things in one. An uri scheme can be registered by a mobile app to receive information through a link. `myapp://share/id` will trigger your app and it will receive /share/id. There is no direct connection to your nextJS webapp, so your app **must** map /share/id to open a browser on an URL that points to your nextJS webapp. There is nothing automatic here, you must implement it.

Comment: But how can I implement that? I just don't know and couldn't find the answer about what I need to do in my nextJS webapp to link it to my React Native app.

Comment: I'm not sure: what's your use case? Do you want to browse webpages and when you click a link that belongs to your domain, it opens your mobile app? That's it, right?
The current best practice is not to use a custom uri scheme because if the application is not installed on the mobile device, the link won't do anything. You can declare your domain inside your app so that it listens for http queries on your domain though.

Comment: I want to share a link via WhatsApp for example that contains my meta tags (already done it in the nextJS application) and when someone access it, it opens my app just like my `myapp://share/id` does. I just don't know if I need to configure something in the nextJS application or in my RN app. (Although I thought that just by putting my nextJS link to my React Navigation prefixes config would done it.)

Comment: Then you do not need a custom uri scheme, you just need to register your domain name inside your app. When a link on your domain is clicked, if your domain is registered by your app, then it'll open, otherwise, the website will open. You should google "universal deep linking react native" or something, you'll find many tutos that will help you to set that up! :)